# How do I keep keyboard input focus on .js game when ads refresh?

Tags: javascript, html, keyboard, focus

I have a website that hosts typing games .js embedded into HTML. The game pages also have ads that refresh every minute. The refresh of the ads is causing keyboard function in many of my games to lose "focus" on the game (for example, someone typing can no longer type until they click on the game again).

Is there a way to keep the keyboard's focus on the game?

Comment: I'm not too familiar working with ads, but are the ads not refreshed asynchronously?

Comment: I'll have to check with the ad company, but I believe (due to header bidding) there might be a small delay between ads (like fractions of a second). All 3 ads are different though.

Comment: Here is a little more about what I was talking about. This will help a lot of you use adsense https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/3221666?hl=en